# Разбиение строки по разделителю

Tags: delphi, оптимизация

Как оптимально разбить строку по разделителю?
Тестовый пример: (выполняется ~3 мин)

```
For I := 1 To 1000000000 Do //1 Млрд
begin
  MakeSheet('A');
  MakeSheet('B');
  MakeSheet('C');
end;
```

А теперь вызываем с разбиением строки:

```
For I := 1 To 1000000000 Do //1 Млрд
begin
  MakeSheets('A B C');
end;

Procedure MakeSheets(Str: String);
Var
  SL: TStringList;
  S: String;
Begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  Try
    SL.Delimiter := ' ';
    SL.DelimitedText := Trim(Str);
    For S In SL Do
      MakeSheet(S);
  Finally
    SL.Free;
  End;
End;
```

Выполняется ~15 мин. В общем хотелось бы, чтобы эти 12 минут не съедались... Ну или по крайней мере не так жестоко. Естественно 'A', 'B', 'C' могут быть разной длины, просто для примера упростил.

PS: Кстати, как это ни странно, но конструкция

```
For S In SL Do
```

оказалась тоже медленнее, чем

```
For I := 0 To Length(SL) - 1 Do
```

Comment: Вам обязательно разбивать строку? Как вариант, можно передавать внутрь сразу массив строк (`['A', 'B', 'C']`). Также, строки всегда одинаковые? Вынесите их разбиение наружу цикла.

Comment: @Kromster, да, кстати, можно подумать над этим.

Answer (score 3):

Ответ очень простой: `TStringList`, хоть и содержит код для разбиения строк, не оптимизирован для этой задачи. Если вы хотите что-то стандартное и пошустрее, то можете попробовать `StrUtils.SplitString` (Delphi 2010+) или `SysUtils.TStringHelper.Split` (Delphi XE3+). Сорцы не смотрел, но они должны быть пошустрее.

И вы занимаетесь микрооптимизацией, что весело, но бесполезно.

Comment: Жаль, что нельзя отдельно плюсануть за микрооптимизации - если ТС создает 3 млрд листов сходу, то разбиение строк - ничтожнейшая из проблем.

Comment: @Squidward, микрооптимизация это уже диагноз неверное. С определением согласен, но бесполезно ничего не бывает. Это опыт, он всегда полезен! А когда проект большой, а скорость критична, на нахождение узких мест уходит много времени, т.ч. лучше стараться их не использовать на этапе создания. 
SplitString отиграл назад 5 мин, столо 10 вместо 15, но сдаётся мне это всё равно много.

Answer (score 2):

Нужен именно TStringList? **array of string** не подойдёт?

```html
type
  TStringArray = array of string;

// разбивает строку по любым разделителям, по умолчанию - знак табуляции
function SplitS(S: String; Delimiter:TSysCharSet = [#9]): TStringArray;
var
   len, idx1, idx2, idx: integer;
begin
     Result := nil;
     if Length(S) = 0 then Exit;
     len := Length(S);
     SetLength(Result, len);
     idx2 := 1;
     idx := 0;
     repeat
       idx1 := idx2;
       while (idx2 <= len) and not(S[idx2] in Delimiter) do inc(idx2);
       if idx1 <= idx2 then
       begin
          Result[idx] := (Copy(S, idx1, idx2-idx1));
          inc(idx);
       end;
       if (idx2 <= len) and (S[idx2] in Delimiter) then inc(idx2);
     until idx2 > len;
     SetLength(Result, idx);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Микрооптимизация?

Посмотрим, что ещё, и если в цикле, то много-много раз делает код MakeSheets:

```
Procedure MakeSheets(Str: String);
Var
  SL: TStringList;
  S: String;                                // Initialize(S); try
Begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;                 // TStringList.Create;
  Try
    SL.Delimiter := ' ';           // Work+
    SL.DelimitedText := Trim(Str); // Work+ 
    For S In SL Do                          // TStringsEnumerator.Create; try
      MakeSheet(S);                // Work!
                                            // finally TStringsEnumerator.Free end;
  Finally
    SL.Free;                                // TStringList.Free;
  End;
End;                                        // finally Finalize(S); end;
```

Итак, на CPU@2GHz 12 дополнительных минут - это 1440 тактов на каждый такой цикл.
Не так уж и много для такого вороха рутинных дел )

Если интересно, насколько затратно разбить строку по разделителю, можно для сравнения протестировать и такой код:

```
uses StrUtils;

procedure MakeSheetsSlim(const Str: String);
var
  s: String;
begin
  for s in SplitString(Trim(Str), ' ')   // Work+
    do MakeSheet(s);                     // Work!
end;
```

Но в нём тоже есть лишнее - создание/освобождение 1+N строк и динамического массива под них.

Вот как простая микрооптимизация может прояснить тонкости использования инструмента.

Answer (score 1):

Cверх быстрой работы с помошью StrUtils.SplitString (Delphi 2010+) или SysUtils.TStringHelper.Split не добиться основная проблема это то что TStringHelper.Split постоянно вызывает setlength для нового array но если написать свою split куда будет передаваться выходной array значений  с зарезервированной длинной array скорость значительно повысится

```
  AmStringSplit = class
  // result count Length Array
     class function Split(Separator:string; S:String;var A:TArray<string>):Integer;  inline;

     // type TArray<string>
     class function SplitForArrayOfString(Separator:string; S:PString;ArrayOfString:Pointer):Integer;   inline;

     // type TArrStr
     class function SplitForArrStr(Separator:string; S:PString;ArrStr:Pointer):Integer; inline;


     // type custom pointer  DynArrayString = та ссылка что вернет DynArraySetLength(); и ее подобные
     class function SplitArrayCustomPointer(Separator:string; S:PString;DynArrayString:Pointer;CountMax:Integer):Integer;  inline;
  end;



class function AmStringSplit.Split(Separator:string; S:String;var A:TArray<string>):Integer;
begin
 Result:= SplitForArrayOfString(Separator,@S,@A);
end;
class function AmStringSplit.SplitForArrayOfString(Separator:string; S:PString;ArrayOfString:Pointer):Integer;
begin
  //   var A:TArray<string>;
  //SetLength(A,20);
  //Count:= SplitForArrayOfString(Separator,@S,@A);

  Result:= SplitArrayCustomPointer(Separator,S,PPointer(ArrayOfString)^,length(Tarray<string>(PPointer(ArrayOfString)^)));
end;
class function AmStringSplit.SplitForArrStr(Separator:string; S:PString;ArrStr:Pointer):Integer;
var L:PArrStr;
begin
  // var A:TArrStr;
  //A.count:=20;
  // SplitForArrStr(Separator,@S,@A);
   L:= PArrStr(ArrStr);
   Result:= SplitArrayCustomPointer(Separator,S,L.ArrayInstancePointer,L.Capacity);
   L.Count:=Result;
   L.UpdateA;
end;
class function AmStringSplit.SplitArrayCustomPointer(Separator:string; S:PString;DynArrayString:Pointer;CountMax:Integer):Integer;
var
u,y:integer;
sl:string;
begin
  y:=1;
  Result:=0;
  if (length(Separator)=0) or (length(S^)=0) then exit;
  while y<=Length(s^) do
  begin
      u:=pos(Separator,s^,y);
      if u<>0 then
      begin
        if Result>=CountMax-1 then
        raise Exception.Create('Error AmStringSplit.SplitArrayCustomPointer Размер array превышен');

        TArray<string>(DynArrayString)[Result]:=(Copy(s^,y,u-y));
        y:=u+length(Separator);
      end
      else
      begin
        if Result>=CountMax-1 then
        raise Exception.Create('Error AmStringSplit.SplitArrayCustomPointer Размер array превышен');
        TArray<string>(DynArrayString)[Result]:=(Copy(s^,y,Length(s^)-y+1));
        y:=Length(s^)+1;
      end;
      inc(Result);
  end;
  sl:=Copy(s^,length(s^)-length(Separator)+1,length(Separator));
  if sl=Separator then
  begin
        if Result>=CountMax-1 then
        raise Exception.Create('Error AmStringSplit.SplitArrayCustomPointer Размер array превышен');
    TArray<string>(DynArrayString)[Result]:='';
    inc(Result);
  end;

end;
```